# How much is the Plan: Staff of Herding worth?

Tags: diablo-iii

I just got the Plan: Staff of Herding and was wondering what the drop rate was because a friend of mine wants to buy it. I know you can't put it on the auction house, so it's hard to estimate the price. Anyone else know how much it is worth?

Comment: 1 zillion dollars ... -Dr. Evil

Comment: I don't know about this item specifically, but the rest are "account bound" - which means I don't think you can trade them, auction house or not.

Comment: On which difficulty does the plan drop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The items for the Staff of Herding, including the Plan: Staff of Herding are "Account Bound" meaning they are only available to your Battle.Net account. If you want to give it to your buddy the only way is giving him your account password, and you shouldn't do that. You could say it's worth about as much as your battle.net account is worth :)

About your title questions: I killed Izual about 5 times before it dropped. Of course this is definitely not a scientific answer.

Comment: I found the drop rate is rather high, I have killed him 7 times now (1 Normal, 5 NM and 1 Hell) and I have gotten the plans 3 times.

Comment: @Blem Whereas I killed him roughly the same number of times on Normal, and only got a single plan.  It should be mentioned, though, that I was specifically attempting to find said plans, so once I found them, I stopped killing him.

Comment: I also got it after around 5 tries (incl. first one where I killed him before knowing about the plans, and he didn't drop them either)