# Do you need Magic Find to drop the new "Legendary" quality "Plan: Staff of Herding"?

Tags: diablo-iii

With the recent change to Staff of Herding and all its components going from Normal (White) to Legendary (Orange), does it affect the drop chance for the Plan from Izual (Act4)?

I was reading before this change that you should take off any nephalem valors and any magic find gear to improve the chance to drop the plan, since it was a poorer quality item.

Now that the item has changed to legendary, do I need to stack Magic Find in order to get it to drop?

Also does it matter if I farm the plan on Normal Difficulty or Nightmare/Hell difficulty? Or do the plans drop in all difficulties?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the drop rate for the Plan: Staff of Herding?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70739/what-is-the-drop-rate-for-the-plan-staff-of-herding)

Comment: It does affect it, otherwise I would not have gotten it 3 times in a row with 350 MF. The drop chance is not that high otherwise.

Comment: The reason that it's legendary is simply so that it's easy to spot on the ground.  I don't know about the magic find/nephalem valor claim.  Seems dubious to me.

Comment: Well its easy to proof for whomever wants to invest the time. Do 10-20 Izual runs with 0 MF, and compare the drop rate to the equal amount of runs with 300+ MF. As already stated I tested it 3 times and I am quite certain it does affect it. Please do not argue with "I think..." or "Seems dubious..." as this is QA not a forum. This criticism is directed towards the current answers.

Comment: @ayckoster: You can't be certain with only 3 runs.  It's statistically impossible to be certain with 3 runs.  3 runs shows a trend, that's it.  It's a beacon to a statistician saying "Hey, look at me!  I could become statistically significant, if you only run more tests!"  If you want to back up your claim, do _at least_ 30 runs with your magic find gear.

Comment: @MBraedley: The significance depends on the number of tries and on the drop chance. If the drop chance is very low (e.g. 2% and not your 10%), few "positive" tries are necessary to prove the significance (say I make 30 runs and the first 3 are positive its still 10% and 10 >> 2). But be my guest and prove me wrong with your 30 runs each. I claim that the answers presented here have absolutely no data to back them up. As you seem so willing to claim otherwise do it yourself, I have provided my answer with some data I have gathered and I will not change it until proven false :).

Comment: I think most of us are drawing from previous Diablo / Blizzard games. Things like Plans of Herding in the past have had their own drop rate regardless of MF. As such, I think it's best to disprove the past experiences with extra runs, @ayckoster. The burden of proof shouldn't be on us. (Sidenote: I've gotten it 5 times in a row with 0% MF. There's some "data", but I hope you get that 3 or 5 runs isn't enough to make a better claim than relying on past experiences with Diablo 2 / Blizzard)

Comment: With the way drops work in the game Izual would have increased chance of dropping any plans if the Plan: Staff of herding was not in its own category of drops.

Comment: So the plans are no longer purchasable from the vendor in Act IV??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the way magic find works has no effect on items like the plans for staff of herding. Also taking off nephalem valor would not affect the outcome either.

The way magic find works is once the type of item that will drop is chosen it increases the chance that it will be a magic/rare/legendary/set item. But since the plans for staff of herding is most likely in its own category, it can not drop as anything other than it self and Magic Find will not effect its drop chance.

The difficulty you farm in does not matter towards your chance of getting them, it is just a question of how fast you can kill the boss or maybe get xp/usable loot while doing it.

Comment: Do you have any proof whatsoever?

Comment: what kind of proof are you looking for? I applied the knowledge we have about how drops work to the plans for staff of herding, if you want to know more about it there are plenty of posts here asking about how MF work in general.

Comment: @ayckoster: The onus is just as much on you to prove that magic find does effect the drop rate.  Getting the plan 3 times in a row is merely a 1 in 1000 chance (assuming a 10% chance of dropping), which is entirely in the realm of possibility.  Do 50 runs and tell us your drop rate then.

Comment: @ayckoster There is simple deductive theoretical proof. First, the game decides what item type to drop (for SoH plan the type must be plan) then it decides item lvl (1 for SoH plans). Magic find DOES NOT affect these decisions. Next, the item rarity is decided and this is affected by magic find, but since the only SoH plans with ilvl 1, there is nothing else to drop, so a SoH plan must be dropped. Hence, mf does not affect chances of getting SoH plans.

Answer (score 2):

I have had the plan drop hundreds of times for me, and I can tell you that magic find doesn't really affect the rate at which the plan drops. The biggest thing that does is the skill level you play on. Although you can get it to drop on any skill, due to the plan being of lower level (higher level plans for the staff are bought, not found), it's more likely you will get it to drop on normal. I have had it drop on all skill levels, but the drop rate on normal is much higher than any other.

Answer (score 1):

No I don't think so. It just dropped for me, but if you do have magic find items, then equip them in case.

I had the plans drop in nightmare, but I don't think it matters.

Comment: dropped in normal for me

Comment: My bother also got it in normal mode.