# Diablo 3 - Magic Find In Groups

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does X% Chance of Finding Magical Items work for a party?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49461/how-does-x-chance-of-finding-magical-items-work-for-a-party)

So I'm running Izual on Normal with a friend, who's having trouble getting the Staff of Herding recipe from him. My question is, how does magic find work since each player in a group will get a different set of items when Izual dies? Since my friend needs the plans, should he be the one striking the killing blow? Or can I?

Comment: See also http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70739/what-is-the-drop-rate-for-the-plan-staff-of-herding

Comment: Magic find may not affect the Staff of Herding at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When played cooperatively items drop separately for each player. This means each player sees their own loot and not loot that has dropped for the other people in the group. When picked up and dropped on the ground or traded the items obviously become visible to the other players as well.

**When playing in a group, the total Magic Find of the group will be divided equally amongst each player**. Here is an example given by Blizzard:

> The group consists of four players. In total, their stats are 50% MF, +20% GF and 10% XP, each of these players will have a 12.5% ​​MF, 5% GF and 2.5% XP being in such a group.

Who deals the killing blow doesn't matter.